# Working of fork() in C++

Tags: c++, fork

I have this program in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"*\n";
    fork();
    cout<<"A\n";
    fork();
    cout<<"B\n";
    fork();
    cout<<"C\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
*
A
B
C
*
A
B
C
```

I think it should be:

```
*
A
B
C
A
B
C
B
C
C
```

Explanation: '*' should be printed on by one process. Now, after `fork()` 2 'A' should be printed and son for 'B' & 'C'.

[Link to code](http://ideone.com/mwIaT7)

Comment: I would've expected * A B C * A B C * A B C * A B C * A B C * A B C * A B C * A B C, because of buffering.

Comment: It's indeterminate. If you want a specific order you need to use deterministic methods, not multi-processing. And the behaviour is defined by the operating system, not by C++.

Comment: I can't reproduce your results with either g++ or clang++ locally. What compiler were you using, and on what operating system? I got 1 *, 2 A, 4 B and 8 C, which is what you should _actually_ expect, since each fork() is splitting a process into two.

Comment: @immibis: By default, `cout` is going to be line buffered (if it's going to a terminal), so the buffer would actually have flushed prior to the `fork` in each case unless stdio was intentionally mucked with or output was redirected to a file.

Comment: *
A
B
C
C
B
A
C
B
C
C
B
C
C
C then run 2: *
A
B
A
C
B
C
B
C
B
C
C
C
C
C

Comment: Try replacing `std::cout << "X\n";` with `std::cout << "X" << std::endl;` and you should get something closer to what you expect.

Comment: @EJP I know ordering can vary. I am talking about the no of times each character is to be printed.

Comment: @TBBle http://ideone.com/mwIaT7

Comment: Okay, looks like 'ideone' implements fork() in some way that isn't POSIX. I guess it just starts a second copy of the program, and limits it to once only, to prevent people fork-bombing the compilation server.

Comment: FWIW, on my machine (x86_64/g++/Ubuntu 14.04) I get 2 As, 4 Bs, and 8 Cs, so all the forks succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments on the question, the answer is that `fork` in the [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/) online compiler is simply limiting you to one instance of your process, and buffering your output.

**Update**: Actually, it's also lying: http://ideone.com/oXqqwM shows that `fork()` claims to succeed, but only the first produces a new copy of your process.

I suspect if you checked the return values of `fork()` you'd get some clues as to the surprising behaviour you're seeing -- all but the first will have returned -1 -- and if you used `std::endl` instead you *might* avoid the first `*`.

The expected result is that each `fork()` duplicates the running process at that moment, and so you'd expect to see twice each character compared to the one before, except that buffering means you might still have previous characters in the buffer at the time of `fork()`.

So expect 1 or more "*", 2 or more "A", 4 or more "B" or 8 or more "C", except that if `fork()` fails, the numbers will be capped.

Your expectation of 1 "*", 2 "A", 3 "B" and 4 "C" indicates that you overlooked that *both* processes coming out of a `fork()` will hit the next `fork()`, so you double, rather than incrementing by one.

Comment: Note: Edited after accepting, but I don't think that's an issue here.

Answer (score 0):

so... if you are getting more than one `*` then there is something strange going on, and I suspect that it is implementation specific...
`fork` will give each of the child processes a copy of the file descriptors, including `stdout`... so in your implementation it is also getting a valid copy of the std::cout stream... which already has a buffer loaded with `*`...

I think if you change your program to include a flush, you will see the same thing that I did:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<< "*\n";
    flush(cout);
    fork();
    cout<<"A\n";
    flush(cout);
    fork();
    cout<<"B\n";
    flush(cout);
    fork();
    cout<<"C\n";
    flush(cout);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, `flush()` isn't sufficient. To guarantee anything about ordering in this program, you'd need some sort of interprocess communication.

Comment: It will stop the multiple `*`s though.

Comment: Flushing doesn't buy you ordering but as the answer says, it should get rid of the spurious duplicate characters.

Comment: whoa, whoa, whoa, guys, I said it would display the same sort of thing I got, which in the comment changed between 2 runs... the order of the execution of the child processes isn't deterministic...